# Provide description in SDP format for RTP stream

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc

I'm using LibVLC library 2.1.12 to render an RTP stream to my Android device.

I'm using the following SDP description to request RTP/AV packets to be delivered to the given IP address and port (192.168.0.33, port: 65446)

```
v=0
o=- 1537446049254 1537446050285 IN IP4 192.168.0.33
s=-
c=IN IP4 192.168.0.33
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=video 65446 RTP/AVP 97
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=42e01e;packetization-mode=1
```

On my server (android), I can see the incoming RTP packets.

Code below:

```
private void preparePlayer(ParcelFileDescriptor pfd, VideoStream stream) {
    Media media = new Media(videoView.getVlc(), Uri.parse("rtp://@:" + stream.getLocalPort()));
    media.addOption(":network-caching=5000");
    media.addOption(":clock-jitter=0");
    media.addOption(":clock-synchro=0");
    media.addOption(":codec=all");
    media.addOption(":sout-rtp-description=" + stream.getReceiver().getSessionDescription());
}
```

When I try to provde LibVLC with the stream, I receive the following information in my logs:

```
core input: `rtp://@:65446' successfully opened
rtp demux: unspecified payload format (type 97)
rtp demux: A valid SDP is needed to parse this RTP stream.
core demux: SDP required
core demux: A description in SDP format is required to receive the RTP 
stream. Note that rtp:// URIs cannot work with dynamic RTP payload 
format (97).
rtp demux: added RTP source (58a1ef57)
rtp demux: unknown payload (97)
```

1. How can I provide the description in SDP format to LibVLC (on Android)?
2. Is there another way that I can provide the raw stream packets to the LibVLC VideoView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--sout-rtp-sdp=<string>`

More info at https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

> I'm using LibVLC library 2.1.12

Which wrapper are you using? I strongly advise you to upgrade to libvlc 3+