# How to show video (no audio) from ffmpeg via RTP in VLC?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, rtp, sdp

I'm trying to stream RTP (video only) from ffmpeg to VLC:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i video.mp4 -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://0.0.0.0:1235
```

In VLC app, I do file -> "open network" and set the url to rtp://@:1235.
But I get an error:

```
SDP required
A description in SDP format is required to receive the RTP stream.
Note that rtp:// URIs cannot work with dynamic RTP payload format (96).
```

What am I doing wrong? I see in ffmpeg's output that SDP is being generated:

```
SDP:
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 58.20.100
m=video 1235 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:1205
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=Z01AH9oBQBbsBEAAAAMAQAAADIPGDKg=,aO88gA==; profile-level-id=4D401F
```

Comment: maybe ask on superuser?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425303/provide-description-in-sdp-format-for-rtp-stream/52484940#52484940, you need to provide more info to VLC