# SDP required - Streaming media (RTP) from an embedded board to VLC

Tags: c, embedded, vlc, rtp, sdp

I am having trouble streaming a video with RTP (over UDP) in a **multicast** session to VLC.

The streaming is done from Zedboard (evaluation board), that runs FreeRTOS and lwIP as TCP/IP stack,
and I want to play the video on my laptop via VLC.

Both the board and my laptop are connected to each other via Ethernet cable.

The code for my SDP packet (implemented in C):

```
u8 sdp_payload[1024] = "v=0\r\n"
    "o=guy 2890844526 2890842807 IN IP4 192.168.1.7\r\n"
    "s=bwv\r\n"
    "i=A test in streaming a video from zedboard\r\n"
    "c=IN IP4 224.1.1.1/127\r\n"
    "t=2873397496 0\r\n"
    "a=recvonly\r\n"
    "m=video 5006 RTP/AVP 96";
ssize_t retval = sendto(sock, sdp_payload, strlen(sdp_payload),
            0, (struct sockaddr *)&to, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

(I am sending this packet first and right after I am sending the RTP data containing hex values of the video).

On wireshark I get:
[RTP session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfhQY.png)

With the payload correctly displayed in the first sent package.
However, on VLC I still get the error

```
SDP required: A description in SDP format is required to receive the RTP stream. Note that rtp:// URIs cannot work with dynamic RTP payload format (96).
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52484940/4064749

Comment: I can't seem to configure VLClib with my OS - FreeRTOS + lwIP... So my idea was to implement the SDP payload myself.