# RTP stream with LibVLCSharp (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, vlc, rtp, libvlcsharp

I trying to play live RTP stream using the LibVLCSharp on Windows 10.

I use the LibVLCSharp and LibVLCSharp.WPF NuGet libraries.

Following is the code I am executing:

```
LibVLC libVLC = new LibVLC();
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(libVLC);

Media m = new Media(_libVLC, "rtp://@:7777/", FromType.FromLocation);
mediaPlayer.Play(m);
```

I receive the following message:

```
main demux meta debug: no meta reader modules matched
main input debug: `rtp://@:7777/' successfully opened
rtp demux error: unspecified payload format (type 96)
rtp demux: A valid SDP is needed to parse this RTP stream.
main demux error: SDP required
main demux error: A description in SDP format is required to receive the RTP stream. Note that rtp:// URIs cannot work with dynamic RTP payload format (96).
rtp demux debug: added RTP source (bfccda8c)
rtp demux debug: unknown payload (96)
```

What am I missing?

I can provide more information if needed.
Thank you

Comment: dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52425303/provide-description-in-sdp-format-for-rtp-stream/52484940#52484940

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to write a SDP file somewhere to describe your stream, and play that sdp file : https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=149657

A StreamMediaInput might work instead of writing the file somewhere, but I did not test.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Do you know where I can find the instructions on how to build the SDP file?

Comment: Don't know, never wrote one. There is an example in the forum topic I linked. Please share your solution once you found it.